# How to install the 16 "free DLC" packs (GOG Galaxy)?

Tags: the-witcher-3, gog, gog-galaxy

I understand that the DLC packs have been bundled as one package, but have to be installed separately (GOG).  I have the GOG version, regional game extras have been cut off from the image (GOG Galaxy client page for the game).

[image]

---

**DLC packs**:

1. Temerian Armor Set
2. Beard and Hairstyle Set for Geralt
3. New Quest - Contract: Missing Miners
4. Alternative Look for Yennefer
5. Nilfgaardian Armor Set
6. Crossbow Set - Three New Crossbows
7. New Quest: Fool's Gold
8. Neutral Gwent Card Set: Ballad Heroes
9. New Quest - Scavenger Hunt: Wolf School Gear
10. Triss Alternative Costume
11. New Quest - Contract: Skellige’s Most Wanted
12. Skellige Armor Set
13. New Quest: Where the Cat and the Wolf Play
14. Ciri Alternative Outfit
15. New Finisher Animations
16. New Game +

Comment: If I recall correctly if you are using GOG Galaxy those should automatically download when you download the game through Galaxy it's been awhile since I did install Witcher 3 though so I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Buy" "[free DLC program](https://www.gog.com/game/the_witcher_3_wild_hunt_free_dlc_program)" from GOG. Then download free DLC program from your [GOG account page](https://www.gog.com/account) and install. If installed via GOG Galaxy **after the main game** entire Witcher 3 (~ 25 GB) will be downloaded again.

[image]

[Source](https://www.gog.com/forum/the_witcher_3_wild_hunt/guide_free_dlcs_activasion/page1)

Comment: I don't know why you deleted your previous answer, but just in case: You can edit your posts if you feel it's necessary. You can even edit other people's posts.

Comment: @Nolonar: I didn't have my new answer ready yet, the earlier was false.